# symfony2 override model validation

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm using FOS User Bundle and I want to override the validation file FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/validaiton.xml:

```
<constraint name="FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique">
    <option name="property">usernameCanonical</option>
    <option name="message">fos_user.username.already_used</option>
    <option name="groups">
        <!-- <value>Registration</value> -->
        <value>Profile</value>
    </option>
</constraint>
```

username is not in my Registration form (I just set it to hidden), that's the validation should not produce any error...

Maybe there is a better way to remove the username of the form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the username field of the form in a proper way, you should override the `RegistrationFormType`, creating your own and extending it from the original FOSUserBundle

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'email')
                ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password'))

                // your other custom fields, if any.

    }
}
```

Now, you should declare the overrided form as a service, and then tell to FOSUserBundle configuration file that you are using now an overrided form. [Here is the complete documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md).

Comment: sry, this doesnt work. It still asks for a username. So I think the validation is still active.

Answer (score 1):

You can put entity validation info in any `validation.yml` file. So you can do

```
#validation.yml
FQCN\Of\User\Entity:
  constraints:
    - FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique:
        property: usernameCanonical
        groups: [Profile]
        message: fos_user.username.already_used


  properties:
  # property validations here
```